# Error in syntax of MySQL query, cannot figure it out

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pic_hours
AFTER INSERT ON CREW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.CREW_JOB = 'Pilot' THEN
  UPDATE PILOT
  SET PIL_PIC_HOURS = PIL_PIC_HOURS+(SELECT CHAR_HOURS_FLOWN FROM CHARTER
     WHERE CHAR_TRP = NEW.CHAR_TRP)
       WHERE EMP_NUM = NEW.EMP_NUM;
  END IF;
END;
```

It errors out on NEW.CHAR_TRP but if I remove the NEW it processes but does not work correctly.  Any idea why?

Comment: I would guess NEW is not available in a subquery; perhaps assigning it to and using a variable would work?  Or change the subquery to a join?

Comment: Trigger code is synthactically correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a6c55b9eb14661aeb1b436dac16f70a. Show CREATE TABLE for all tables. *It errors out on NEW.CHAR_TRP* Provide complete error message, not a tale about it.